# Long time to load first sql connection in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

For some reason it takes 7 seconds to open a connection to a sql server database for the firt time, subsequent connections takes a second. any idea what could be the reason?

I'm using C# and asp.net

Its after compilation, i essence every time i restart the site, which means every time it needs to actualy create the "first" connection. i understand that setting up connection pooling has overhead, but i have never seen that i should take 7 second to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as connection pooling and CLR compilation, don't forget that the data and plan caches on the database server could be "cold" too...

I've seen first calls on a very "cold" web site take 5-10 seconds to respond from button click (for example, "search") to the data ending up on screen.

Answer (score 1):

The first time the connection has to be established which has a lot of overhead.  Each subsequent connection is using connection pooling (assuming you have the same connection string) and the initial setup does not need to be done.

Edit: see [this link](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/040830.htm) or [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) for some info on connection pooling.

Comment: I understand the reason, but i have not seen anywhere that it should take 7 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

is this after a compile each time? Is the "lagtime" due to JIT compiling rather than the SqlConnection itself?

Comment: I updated my question to answer your question, i short it's compilation.